# Overriding Rails engine model using concerns, getting uninitialized constant Concerns::Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload, activesupport-concern

I'm following Rails guide to [override engine models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers), I'm using an `ActiveSupport::Concern` to override it.

I've created a module inside the engine in `seven_gallery/lib/concerns/models/gallery.rb` that contains the following code:

```
module SevenGallery::Concerns::Models::Gallery
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
        default_scope { order("created_at desc") }
    end
end
```

And changed `seven_gallery/app/models/seven_gallery/gallery.rb` code to:

```
module SevenGallery
  class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SevenGallery::Concerns::Models::Gallery
  end
end
```

Now inside my host application where I've included my engine in `Gemfile` by

```
gem "seven_gallery", path: "../seven_gallery"
```

I have a `User` model that contains:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :gallery, class_name: SevenGallery::Gallery
end
```

But whenever I run the application I get this error on the only line inside the `User` model:

```
uninitialized constant Concerns::Models
```

Comment: well - if it's any comfort to you - I'm "dead in the water" with more or less that exact same problem :(

Comment: @walt_die I've found the solution. Please check the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone facing the same problem. Turns out it's because the documentation isn't clear enough and has some flaws.

Please check this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-docs/Oo68KwRdwyo